# Using parse.com facebook log in - getting Param third_party_app_id must be a valid application id

Tags: android, parse-platform, facebook-login

I'm trying to set up the facebook log in of the parse SDK. I followed the steps listed [here](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#users-facebook-users)

but when I try to log in with Facebook I,m getting this:

```
06-06 23:01:37.733   7366-30131/? W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue﹕ Exception during service
com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: [code] 100 [message]: (#100) Param third_party_app_id must be a valid application id [extra]:
        at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.b(ApiResponseChecker.java:104)
        at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.a(ApiResponseChecker.java:137)
        at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.a(ApiResponseChecker.java:234)
        at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.a(ApiResponseChecker.java:185)
        at com.facebook.http.protocol.JsonResponseHandler.a(JsonResponseHandler.java:34)
        at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseHandler.b(ApiResponseHandler.java:93)
        at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseHandler.a(ApiResponseHandler.java:54)
        at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseHandler.handleResponse(ApiResponseHandler.java:29)
        at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:1004)
        at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:305)
        at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:247)
        at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:98)
        at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor$Dispatcher.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:1215)
        at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor$Dispatcher.run(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:1207)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at com.facebook.common.executors.ConstrainedListeningExecutorService$Worker.run(ConstrainedListeningExecutorService.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at com.facebook.common.executors.NamedThreadFactory$1.run(NamedThreadFactory.java:38)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a meta-data element to the application element:

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" ...>
...
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
...
```

Make sure to add:

```
<string name="facebook_app_id">YOUR_APP_ID</string>
```

to your strings.xml file